# Short story about a man who claimed could wiggle his bottom and jump to alternate reality Earths

Tags: story-identification, 2000ad

I'm trying to track down the story which I'd found very funny as a kid and wanted to pass it on my kids:

> He appeared to be a spiv/tramp who had accosted a passer by and told them a
>   fantastical story of how he had spent years wheeling and dealing/making money by moving stuff between worlds. Eventually he had gone broke due to losing tracking of which was the 'real' Earth - where all his money was- and was now destitute. He was basically begging for a pound to buy a cup of tea.

The nub of the story was that

> he had not kept pace with the changes in the real 'earth' and when presented with a pound coin as opposed to a pound note, he instantly assumed that that is was one of the many that had had only minor differences. With that he wiggled his bottom and disappeared.

I'm pretty sure it was 2000ad as Tornado had already been subsumed by 2000ad in 1979 and the pound coin was not introduced until 1983. Also didn't ever buy Eagle  - I only bought graphical comics from about 1977 to the mid 80s and Eagle was not published in that period I believe. It was part of the 'Future-Shock' series of short stories.

Comment: how long ago are we talking? what format was the story in? Was it definitely in 2000ad, or could it have been in one of the others that was around back in the day like Eagle, Tornado, Crisis, Wildcat etc...? If it was 2000ad try Barney (www.2000ad.org) which lists the stories in every prog.

Comment: also, if we are talking 2000ad, was it a done in one (e.g. Tharg's Future Shocks) or a multi part story?

Comment: I'm certain this was a 2000ad story. I seem to recall that the title character was a spiv type

Comment: You are definitely right there @Richard - he was a spiv but I thought I'd leave that out of the question.

Comment: @PreetSangha - I'd have found it ten times quicker if you'd put that in :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was "[The Startling Success of Sideways Scuttleton](http://www.comics.org/issue/164653/)", originally published as a *Time Twister* story in 2000AD #327 but later collected in the [Complete Alan Moore Future Shocks](http://www.comics.org/series/18753/)

[image]

and at the end...

> [image: hidden picture]

Comment: You can find it in the Alan Moore's Future Shocks collection, if you don't feel like tracking down an individual prog.

Comment: You can leave the other image in, hidden in a spoiler tag just like the clue in the question.